# creating encoder and decoder as seperate models from unet with skip connections using keras

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Simple Unet model with skip connections

```
# u-net model

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, concatenate, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import MeanIoU

kernel_initializer =  'he_uniform'  


def simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS=3):

    inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
    


    #Contraction path
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(inputs)
    # c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p1)
    # c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p2)
    # c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)

    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p3)
    # c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)

    c41 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p4)
    # c41 = Dropout(0.3)(c41)
    c41 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c41)
    p41 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c41)

    c5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p41)
    # c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
    c5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c5)

    #Expansive path
    u61 = Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
    # u61 = concatenate([u61, c41])
    c61 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u61)
    # c61 = Dropout(0.2)(c61)
    c61 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c61)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c61)
    # u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u6)
    # c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c6)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
    # u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u7)
    # c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c7)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
    # u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u8)
    # c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c8)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
    # u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u9)
    # c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c9)

    outputs = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

this is my code. Just basic convolution and concatenation layers. i want to make two separate models, from pretrained residual unet, one is encoder to encode image and decoder to decode the latent vector to image. Creating encoder is simple

```
def image_encoder():
    outputof = our_model.layers[22]
    need_model = Model(inputs = our_model.input, outputs = outputof.output)
    need_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    return need_model
```

But decoder's skip connections need input from encoder but as we are making decoder separate model we don't have excess to encoder information.

I'm trying to use these models in stable diffusion. Is there other autoencoders available that I can separate and use them in stable diffusion?